# How do I create a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a one to one relationship with Shares and Testimonials.

In Testimonial.rb:

```
belongs_to :share
```

In Share.rb:

```
has_one :testimonial
```

I want to add a form to the Shares page where I can create a testimonial which belongs to that specific share.

Inside the SharesController I set:

```
@testimonial = @share.build_testimonial
```

In the Shares view I have:

```
<%= form_for @testimonial do |f| %>  
 <%= f.text_area :message %>
<%= f.submit "Submit testimonial" %>
```

Is the above correct or do I have to add the share object to the view somehow?

What do I add to the create action in the Testimonials controller to create the testimonial and associate it with the `@share` object?

I have tried to send the `share_id` to the Testimonials controller from the view as an additional param and then used a "before" filter to find the share object but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `share.rb` model, you'd want to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :testimonial
```

Since you are in the `share` view, I would think you'd have a construct in that view of:

```
<%= form_for @share do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In that context, to use the `testimonial` fields:

```
<%= form_for @share do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for @share.testimonial do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_area :message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I want to use the Testimonials create action instead of the Shares Edit (put) action. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @spuggy perhaps this really should be a testimonial view rather than a share view then.

Comment: On my share page I have a partial which creates a testimonial and another partial which creates feedback. I can't have it on its own page if that's what you mean

Comment: @spuggy, Your share page would still have the `form_for @share` wouldn't it? Then in the call to the partial for the feedback, you could pass the `f` from this `form_for` and use the above code for `fields_for`. Maybe it would be clearer if you shared a little more of the view code in your question.